# how can I get old revision as master on git without merge?

Tags: git, github

I'm working on my localhost.  i want to get my old commit that is `git checkout revision_id` .   when I merge this `git merge` then it merges with master. but don't want that.
how to make that revision as a master branch.
I trying to `git commit --amend` but it is not working for me.

Comment: Are you asking how to reset your master branch to a specific commit?

Comment: yes. i want to make old commit back as a master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just `reset` your `master` branch:

```
$ git reset <commit-hash> --hard
```

Answer (score 1):

For example `8ec94b3` is the commit hash string what you want go to back. Use command:

```
git checkout 8ec94b3
```

The above command only affects your Git local repository, doesn't affect to Git remote repository.

Comment: but it's changed HEAD of the branch. i want HEAD as master branch